# vb.net Autologin to website

Tags: vb.net

I have an app that autologins to a website which works fine.  I want to check the checkbox to "remember me"  Below is the source code on the side, how do I check it in my vb code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" value="1" tabindex="3"  name="rm">
        <label id="rm_label" for="remember_me" title="Keep me signed in.">Keep me signed in.</label>
```

Here is my code for the login/pw/sign in that works fine.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").InnerText = "johndoe"
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").InnerText = "test"
WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.forms(0).submit()
```

I've tried

```
   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("remember_me").SetAttribute(1) and
```

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("remember_me").ID = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the attribute `checked` to true you can use this `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("remember_me").SetAttribute("checked","true")`